# Perpendiculars to two vectors facing roughly the same direction

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to find a way to construct perpendiculars to two vectors such that those perpendiculars roughly point in the same direction. That is, given `A` and `B` I wish to find perpendiculars `Ap` and `Bp` such that the angle between `Ap` and `Bp` is a minimum.

The one approach I saw is using the cross product. It provides the equation I need to minimize. For some vector unit `C` I know that `Ap = A × C` and `Bp = B × C`. I could try to find `C` which maximizes `Ap · Bp`. I'm not sure if I can actually solve this optimization though (I did the expansion and it looks daunting).

Is there a simpler approach to this problem?

*Note: I'm aware that `C` could still have an infinite number of possibilities for certain input vectors. I'm okay with this. Any two perpendiculars which have a minimal angle between them is okay.*

---

- `A` and `B` could be nearly parallel and/or exactly parallel
- It can be assume that the angle between `A` and `B` is less than or equal to `90°`. Though a solution which works for strictly less than `90°` might also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the cross product, there is an even simpler solution: the vector $A\times B$ is perpendicular to both $A$ and $B$.

This will even work in dimension higher than $3$, simply be reducing to a $3$-dimensional subspace containing $A$ and $B$.

In dimension $2$, there are only two perpendiculars to $A$ and $B$, so there are then only $4$ possibilities to check.

Comment: It doesn't work when A and B are parallel. In which case the cross-product is a zero vector.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: In that case, you can just choose any vector $C$ perpendicular to $A$. Since $B$ is parallel to $A$, $C$ is automatically perpendicular to $B$.

Comment: I'd like to avoid algorithms which have conditionals triggered by exact values. I'll be implementing this on a computer where such comparisons simply can't be done well.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y If $A\times B$ is numerically near the zero vector, then $A$ must be very close to $B$, so that any vector perpendicular to $A$ is very nearly perpendicular to $B$, too. If you don't need exactness, this should suffice. Unless I misunderstood your objection.

Comment: I believe my objection is based on something I've not actually put in the question. Something about the continuity of the function. I also found the Hairy ball theorem which applies here... In light of that your answer is correct to the given question. I'll try to think if I can phrase a more precise question which captures my issues.